# dateInput in Shiny does not work with spinner

Tags: r, shiny

I am building an app with many charts and using spinners while waiting for them to generate.
I found if I add spinner to the charts, my date input no longer works.
I dont understand this behaviour, nor know how to fix it.

```
Here is my example:

library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinydashboard)
library(highcharter)
library(lubridate)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinycssloaders)

db <- mtcars

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()
body <- dashboardBody(
   h2("Test"),
   box(title = "Date",width =12,
       column(dateInput('startdate','',value = dmy("1/1/2017"), min = NULL, max = NULL,
       format = "yyyy-mm-dd", startview = "month", weekstart = 0,language = "en", width = NULL),width = 3)
   ),
   highchartOutput("hc")%>%withSpinner()
)  
header <- dashboardHeader()
ui <- dashboardPage(header,sidebar,body)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$hc <- renderHighchart({
    hc <- highchart() %>%
      hc_add_series(name = "mpg", data = db$mpg) %>%
      hc_add_series(name = "wt", data = db$wt)
    hc
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If I were to remove `withSpinner()`, I then can select the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a love-hate relationship with those spinners. Anyways: putting your graph in a fluidrow (and column) solved the problem for me:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinydashboard)
library(highcharter)
library(lubridate)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinycssloaders)

db <- mtcars

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

body <- dashboardBody(
    h2("Test"),
    box(title = "Date",width =12,
        column(dateInput('startdate','',value = dmy("1/1/2017"), min = NULL, max = NULL,
                         format = "yyyy-mm-dd", startview = "month", weekstart = 0,language = "en", width = NULL),width = 3)
    ),
    
    fluidRow(
        column(
            width = 12,
            shinycssloaders::withSpinner(highchartOutput("hc"))
        )
    )

)

header <- dashboardHeader()
ui <- dashboardPage(header,sidebar,body)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$hc <- renderHighchart({
        hc <- highchart() %>%
            hc_add_series(name = "mpg", data = db$mpg) %>%
            hc_add_series(name = "wt", data = db$wt)
        hc
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is might suggest it was also weirdly applied to other aspects of your page rather than only your graph?

Comment: Your solution works for me. Though I am not sure if it is applied to any thing else other than my charts. Still curious if this is a bug or not